# Pandas Concat ValueError. shape not matching

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to concat two dataframes but I keep running into an issue that they are not the same size. I have figured out that the issue is due to duplicates on the second column. e.g.

df1 looks like:

```
query   search   value_1
query1  search1  20
query2  search1  15
```

and df2 looks like:

```
query   search   value_2
query1  search2  20
query2  search1  12
```

and I want the final_df to look like:

```
query   search   value_1 value_2
query1  search1  20      NaN
query2  search1  15      12
query1  search2  NaN     20
```

So I think the issue is that the dataframes concat on query which is the index, and the search values are different so it doesn't make enough rows.

Error would be 'ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 4), indices imply (3, 4)' for this

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the data in python?

Comment: I think need outer merge

Comment: @jezrael thanks that gets over the error, but it doesn't keep a unique query for every search

Comment: Ok, can you create example with error raise? Because sample data working perfectly.